# How to restore stdout after using freopen

Tags: c++, redirect, stdout

I try to redirect output in my c++ program from stdout with the following:

```
 freopen(cmd.c_str(),"w",stdout);
```

Then I call system to execute cmd. I have also tried forking and then calling execvp. Either way, when program control returns to my program, things written to stdout are no longer showing. How can normal behavior be restored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect the output back to the screen after freopen("out.txt", "a", stdout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
fclose(stdout);
stdout = fdopen(1, "w"); //reopen: 1 is file descriptor of std output
```

If you can use [STDOUT_FILENO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) from `<unistd.h>`, instead of `1` as first argument to `fdopen`.

Comment: fdopen() fails with "bad file descriptor" error, because after fclose() has been called, this descriptor doesn't exist any more.

Comment: MSVC compiler complains: error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value. Seems that stdout is not assignable.

Comment: No compilation error, but *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution for stdin if doing in loop, needed to figure this out for a program wherein freopen of stdin happens in a loop on some condition. Took some time for me to figure out (with help of search and all) and so posting here

```
savestdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);  
while (1) {  
        .  
        .  
        if (inputfile) {  
              savestdin = dup(savestdin);
              freopen(inputfile, "r", stdin);  
              restorestdin = TRUE;
         }  
        .  
        .  
        if (restorestdin) {  
              fflush(stdin);  
              fclose(stdin);
              stdin = fdopen(savestdin, "r");  
              restorestdin = FALSE;  
        }  
        .  
        .  

}
```

Comment: stdin/stdout are constants no need to" stdin = fdopen". You may just need to do fdopen(0, "r")