# freopen stdout and console

Tags: c, windows, stdout

Given the following function:

```
freopen("file.txt","w",stdout);
```

Redirects stdout into a file, how do I make it so stdout redirects back into the console?

I will note, yes there are other questions similar to this, ***but*** they are about linux/posix. I'm using windows.

You can't assigned to stdout, which nullifies one set of solutions that rely on it.
dup and dup2() are not native to windows, nullifying the other set. As said, posix functions don't apply (unless you count fdopen()).

Comment: Did you try some of the ones posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdou)? How did they fail? (BTW, freopen is POSIX and available on Windows. Windows has some POSIX support.)

Comment: @Mat: Those were for a posix system, as per the question, windows is in use here. If it has posix support you'll have to clarify what (functions) it supports in relation.

Comment: [freopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td(v=vs.80).aspx) - look at the links on the left. I don't have to clarify anything.  You post a question with a function call that is valid on Windows, and there are similar questions that also use APIs available on Windows. (The one that needs to do the research is yourself - you're the one stuck with the problem.)

Comment: `you'll have to` Not really @Mat,or rather anyone else doesn't need to  , No one gets paid to help *you* here. Atleast show a little gratitude instead of *demanding* towards the ones helping you.

Comment: @Als: I am not familiar with the system. If I knew what did and did not work, I would not be asking a question on it. He'll have to show me because I won't know myself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to use [`_dup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dup-dup2) to do this

Something like this should work (or you may prefer the example listed in the `_dup` documentation):

```
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...
{
    int stdout_dupfd;
    FILE *temp_out;

    /* duplicate stdout */
    stdout_dupfd = _dup(1);

    temp_out = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    /* replace stdout with our output fd */
    _dup2(_fileno(temp_out), 1);
    /* output something... */
    printf("Woot!\n");
    /* flush output so it goes to our file */
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(temp_out);
    /* Now restore stdout */
    _dup2(stdout_dupfd, 1);
    _close(stdout_dupfd);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write explicitly `stdout` instead of all this ones?

Comment: @Sandburg: If this wasn't Windows specific, You could include `unistd.h` and write `STDOUT_FILENO` instead (or define `STDOUT_FILENO` to 1 yourself). You could also use `_fileno` to get the `stdout` fd before all of this.

Answer (score 17):

An alternate solution is:

```
freopen("CON","w",stdout);
```

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Device_files) "CON" is a special keyword which refers to the console.

Comment: I tried this - Win7, VS2017 - unfortunately it did no work

Comment: I tested it and yes, it does work. It's the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help @dtyler

Comment: In which environment? For my only the solution with _dup2() worked.

Comment: actually CON: AUX: etc are simply the same as COM1: or A: or C: .. in other words. devices. just that unix places those only in /dev/ as physical 'files' and in dos they are virtually present 'in every directory' (most versions actually have a bug where dir shows them if you specifically type in those names) not so much a 'special keyword'. just a filename that refers to a device. like any other character or block device.

Answer (score 4):

After posting the answer I have noticed that this is a Windows-specific question. The below still might be useful in the context of the question to other people. Windows also provides _fdopen, so mayble simply changing 0 to a proper HANDLE would modify this Linux solution to Windows.

`stdout = fdopen(0, "w")`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    freopen("file.txt","w",stdout);
    printf("dupa1");
    fclose(stdout);
    stdout = fdopen(0, "w");
    printf("dupa2");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fdopen is valid. dup and dup2 are not, and are called _dup and _dup2 in windows instead according to hasturkun. Upvoted for effort. (Ignore what I said about compiler error... my own fault).

Comment: I will tack in that stdout = fdopen(0, "w"); results in the following error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Answer (score 0):

take note that the filedescriptors for stdin, stdout, stderr (0,1,2) are not nessesarily the same as the 'special variables' printf() and the likes use. although in most cases they output to the same devices upon program start. (not if you start changing things in the middle of your program, or tty redirects are in place). stdin stdout stderr are FILE * pointers. both concepts need to be 'redirected' seperately from each other with their own methods... 'dup2' is for duplicating file descriptors. not FILE pointers. for FILE * pointers such as stdin, stdout, stderr... 'freopen()'.. but that will literally only affect printf and derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

This works to me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    FILE* original_stdout = stdout;
    stdout = fopen("new_stdout.txt", "w");
    printf("ciao\n");
    fclose(stdout);
    stdout = original_stdout;
    printf("a tutti\n");
    return 0;
}
```