# C++ Sending Image via HTTP

Tags: c++, http, file-io

I try to implement a simple HTTP server using C++. I was able to send text response to browser, but I am failing to send response for binary file request.

Here is my code to get HTML response to PNG file request:

```
string create_html_output_for_binary(const string &full_path)
{
    const char* file_name = full_path.c_str();

    FILE* file_stream = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    string file_str;

    size_t file_size;

    if(file_stream != nullptr)
    {
        fseek(file_stream, 0, SEEK_END);

        long file_length = ftell(file_stream);

        rewind(file_stream);

        // Allocate memory. Info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/?kw=fread
        char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * file_length);

        if(buffer != nullptr)
        {
            file_size = fread(buffer, 1, file_length, file_stream);

            stringstream out;

            for(int i = 0; i < file_size; i++)
            {
                out << buffer[i];
            }

            string copy = out.str();

            file_str = copy;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("buffer is null!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file_stream is null! file name -> %s\n", file_name);
    }

    string html = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4 \r\n\r\n" + string("FILE NOT FOUND!!");

    if(file_str.length() > 0)
    {
        // HTTP/1.0 200 OK
        // Server: cchttpd/0.1.0
        // Content-Type: image/gif
        // Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
        // Content-Length: 41758

        string file_size_str = to_string(file_str.length());

        html = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: image/png; Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary; Content-Length: " + file_size_str + ";charset=ISO-8859-4 \r\n\r\n" + file_str;

        printf("\n\nHTML -> %s\n\nfile_str -> %ld\n\n\n", html.c_str(), file_str.length());
    }

    return html;
}
```

This code successfully read file and store data on `char* buffer`. 
What makes me confuse is the `file_str` always contains `\211PNG`, although when I check its size, is much large than `\211PNG`.
I suspect this is the problem that cause my image does not loaded in browsers because when I printf the html, it only shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Okay
Content-Type: image/png; Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary; Content-Length: 187542;charset=ISO-8859-4 

\211PNG
```

What I am thinking is the way to send binary data to browser is same with sending text data, so I make the string header first, then read file data, convert it to string and combine with the header, then finally send a large single string to HTTP socket.

I also tried this code:

```
if (file_stream != NULL)
{
    short stringlength = 6;

    string mystring;

    mystring.reserve(stringlength);

    fseek(file_stream , 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&mystring[0], sizeof(char), (size_t)stringlength, file_stream);

    printf("TEST -> %s, length -> %ld\n", mystring.c_str(), mystring.length());

    fclose(file_stream );
}
```

But the HTML output always the same, and `mystring` also contains only `\211PNG` when printf-ed.

Am I in the wrong path? 
Please help find out the mistakes in my code. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the PNG file contains a NULL character. printf's '%s' prints a char string until it encounters NULL and stops. Try using C++ streams instead: cout << mystring;

Comment: You should consider using `std::ifstream` and `std::ostream` rather than the C stream I/O calls.

Comment: This is almost not a C++ but C. Turning to C++ makes things simpler. As the answer below shows. Hacking your way to the solution is definitely one "wrong path".

Comment: There is no need to read the entire file into memory, and certainly no need to convert it from a byte array to any other format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the data in one large chunk into a `std::stringstream`. That will not work as the value zero will be interpreted as a null terminator. This causes everything after the null terminator to be ignored. You should use a container like `std::vector` to store and manage binary data.

```
#include <vector>

string create_html_output_for_binary(const string &full_path)
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    //... other code here

    if(ile_stream != nullptr)
    {
        fseek(file_stream, 0, SEEK_END);
        long file_length = ftell(file_stream);
        rewind(file_stream);

        buffer.resize(file_length);

        file_size = fread(&buffer[0], 1, file_length, file_stream);
    }

    // .... other code here
}
```

To output the data do **not** use `printf`. It may handle new lines differently and will stop at the first null terminator is encounters. Instead (keeping with your use of C stream IO) use `fwrite`.

```
fwrite (buffer.data(), 1 , buffer.size() , stdout );
```

In order for the above to work you will need to reopen the `stdout` to that it writes in binary mode. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664951/845568) here on Stackoverflow shows how to accomplish that. This is just to output the contents to the `stdout` Since you are transmitting the date over sockets you do not have to do anything to `stdout`.

Comment: \0 is only treated specially when converting from const char*, and no length is available.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I've updated it to remove the reference to `string` and updated the description

Comment: Umm.. Then how should I convert the data in vector to string? I've tried `string binary_str(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());`, but still, the string is same `\211PNG` :(

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the use of `fwrite` and a link on how to change `stdout` so that it works in binary mode instead of text to prevent potential mangling  of newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open the file(where your picture is) to read binary.

```
fp=fopen(filename,"rb");
```

Next,set stdout to binary mode with this command:

```
 _setmode(_fileno(stdout),O_BINARY);
```

You need to include `<fcntl.h> and <io.h>` headers.Find the exact size of the picture
you need to send,for example like Captain Obvilous has written:

```
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
long file_length = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
```

Now use fread function to read all bytes from the picture:

```
    while (!feof(fp))
  {
      fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);
      cout << ch;
  }
```

Variable ch is type char.When you are finish set file mode back:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
```

**NOTE:**This code was written mostly in C but you can easily read files in C++ using istream