# How to redirect stderr from inside the process in Rust?

Tags: rust, pipe, stderr

I'm attempting redirect the [`Stderr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stderr.html) file descriptor from inside the process, but there seems to be no implementations of it, and I don't see a clear route to anything similar to `dup2` from C/C++.

I've tried:

- directly implementing `Read` (`impl Read for Stderr`), but it'd take an entire library of code to cover.
- consuming the data in the file descriptor, then into `File`, then into `ReadBuf`

  ```rust
  trait FDReader {
      fn consume(&mut self);
  }

  impl FDReader for Stderr {
      fn consume(&mut self) {
          let f = std::fs::File::from_raw_fd(self.as_raw_fd());
          let mut extract = String::new();
          BufReader::new(f).read_to_string(&mut extract);
      }
  }
  ```

  I focused on `consume` due to the fact I didn't have to exactly return anything when I was testing my code, though this didn't work.
- since I'm running on a Linux system, and I don't plan to publish the code, I also considered redirecting `/proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/null` and then return the original pointer reference when I wanted to write to there. This was way over the top for this scope.

I also *thought* about using `libc::dup2` directly - though I'm weary of it.

Comment: "anything similar to dup2 from C/C++", 1. C/C++ is not a thing 2. `dup2()` is neither a function present in C or C++ standard library. 3. So as in C, your solution will be implementation behavior, thus I think you could find a crate that will do the job for you.

Comment: @Stargateur - [dup2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) (in both C & C++) is a function provided under unistd.h in the posix implementation. I know the implementation was wrong, which is what I asking for help with. Do you have any crates you'd recommend? Might I also add your comment adds no real context to the conversation.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to read the stderr of a child process, or read back what your own process is writing to stderr, or ...?

Comment: @harmic I'm attempting to read (or redirect) my own process's stderr pipe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this in the standard library<sup>1</sup>. The [gag crate](https://crates.io/crates/gag) allows redirecting stderr or stdout either to a file or to nothing, but it only works on *nix systems.

In a different view of the problem, I'd encourage you to **not use stdout or stderr directly** at all. Instead, use *dependency injection* to pass down values that can be written to. Instead of using `println`, use `writeln`.

See also:

- [How can I test stdin and stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370126/155423)

---

**1** This isn't *strictly* true. Have you ever noticed that [stdout and stderr are not output during tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25106554/155423)? That's because the compiler (and the test suite) make use of [a pair of unstable, hidden functions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.32.0/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L622-L667) that allow changing the thread-local instances of stdout and stderr.

See also:

- [Why doesn't println! work in Rust unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25106554/155423)

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX systems (Linux/BSD/MacOS) there is an unsafe (in more than one way) hack that lets you do it on a lower level, using [libc crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc).

Namely, yank and substitute the standard file descriptors 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr) before the program opens any more files.

It relies on the fact that `libc` will assign the first (lowest) descriptor available to a newly open file. This is [guaranteed by POSIX](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

- In C, `FILE* stdout` can be reassigned with [`fdopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen), and, as `printf()` and others work with `FILE* stdout`, this will do the trick.
- But Rust's standard library works with file descriptors, so we have to rely on OS or `libc` implementation details.

I substitute `stdout` descriptor in this example. It worked on MacOS.

```
use std::ffi::c_char;
use libc;


fn main() {

    unsafe {
        let out_file_path = "console.txt".to_string().as_ptr() as *const c_char;
        // let open_flag = libc::O_WRONLY | libc::O_CREAT | libc::O_APPEND | libc::FD_CLOEXEC;

        libc::close(libc::STDOUT_FILENO);
        let new_fd = libc::creat(out_file_path, libc::S_IRUSR | libc::S_IWUSR);
        if new_fd < 0 {
            libc::perror(std::ptr::null());
        }
        eprintln!("new fd: {}, expected {}", new_fd, libc::STDOUT_FILENO);
    }

    println!("Yohoho!");
}
```

There also must be a way to do it on Windows, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664788/freopen-stdout-and-console), but I will leave this as an exercise for the reader.