# How to get back to stdout after redirection?

Tags: c, file, shell, stdout, io-redirection

I have implemented a shell which supports redirection but after the redirtection is done it gets of of my shell. How can I manage it in a way to get back to shell (stdout)?

```
 int i;
     for (i=1; args[i];i++)
         {
           if (strcmp(args[i],">")==0)
             {
               printf("argv[i] %s %d \n", args[i], i);
               int out = open(args[i+1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
               close(1);
               int fdl=dup2(out,1);
               close(out);
               execvp(args[0],args);
            //   open(STDOUT, ">>", \$out); //doesn't work~!
             }

         }
```

Here's what happens when I execute my shell:

```
 ./basic_shell 
mysh> pwd > out_pwd
argv[i] > 1 
pwd: ignoring non-option arguments
```

and it creates out_pwd as expected and writes the pwd result into it.
However when I try

```
mysh>ls > out_ls
```

I receive this error:

```
ls cannot access >: No such file or directory
```

Can you please give me some hints on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of actually transforming file descriptors in your shell process, you want to simply save a representation of the mapping, and perform the replacements in the child after `fork` but before you `exec` the command.

Comment: Doing the I/O redirections in the child processes is basically correct.  Pipes are slightly different; they have to be created before forking, but the redirection is still done after the fork.

Answer (score 0):

First close the handle
Then call AllocConsole in kernel32 / or console api in win 7^ to create console

Comment: OP is asking about POSIX C code, this answer seems to have something to do with Windows. Whoosh.

Comment: here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo