# IO redirect: cout not working in main

Tags: c++, ios, linux, io, pipe

I have a function in which standard output is redirected to a pipe.

I call the function from main, before calling the function, "cout" works fine. After the function, cout<< doesn't output anything, nor does write(1,"",..). But cerr could still output to console.

I think are those IO redirect in the function make cout not work in main.

Is there anyway I could use cout in main ,after the function, to out put to the screen? What's the difference between cout and cerr?

THANKS!

Comment: You really need to post some code to show what you are doing - most likely, you are closing `stdout` and then leaving it closed....

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from another question.
Here's the solution:

```
int o = dup(fileno(stdout));

//call the function that does the IO redirect thing

dup2(o,fileno(stdout));
close(o);
```

It's from [Michael Krelin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo).

Thanks for everyone's help!