# How can I tell the program to stop using freopen

Tags: c++, freopen

I am beginner in C++ and I have a question that is beyond my limits.
I compile under GNU GCC. 
I use

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

also known as:

```
#include<cstdio>
```

At some point in my program I tell the program to use the file de_facut.txt as an in file:

```
freopen("de_facut.txt","r",stdin);
```

How can I tell the program to use the console to put the input (as default) instead of the **in** file?
First I want to read from that file, but later **in** the program I want the user to enter input in the console.
I hope you understood my problem, I am not very good at english.

Comment: Why are you using `freopen` at all? In fact, why are you using C functions at all? This is C++! Use `std::cin` for your console input, and a `std::ifstream` for your file input. Nothing more complicated than that...

Comment: I don't want to use streams. I resolved my problem, read my comment for the other guy (if you want).

Comment: If you're learning C++ you should learn C++. It's up to you of course, but if you want to develop marketable skills then you might consider listening to the experts ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use `fclose()`:

```
FILE *fp=freopen("data.txt","r",stdin);
/*your code here*/
fclose(fp);
```

ref: [C library function - freopen()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_freopen.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The same question has been asked about **stdout**: [How to redirect the output back to the screen after freopen("out.txt", "a", stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo), but the answer is the same for both - **there's no clean way of doing this**: http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html

Since you do need to read from the console later in the program, I'd suggest you just open the file as, well, a file. If the reason you wanted to use `stdin` to read from a file is the convenience of not having to pass the file handle to functions like `fscanf`, you could consider using fstream facilities instead - the code can look exactly as when reading from the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x; // reading from console
    {
        ifstream cin("input.txt");
        cin >> x; // reading from file
    }
    cin >> x; // again from console

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand my question at all... Anyway thank you for the help, I resolved the problem myself... I use now global FILE * fin; and FILE * fout; and close the files where I need to read from console.

Comment: @the_young_programmer: Alpha understood the question perfectly. That you don't like the answer doesn't make it any less accurate. Also, if you found a solution, you should post it as an answer so that it may assist future readers. When you post a question here it is not just for you!

Answer (score 1):

In windows,

```
freopen("CON","r",stdin);
```

this code worked for me. It switches the stdin to console. 
P.S: The text file used to take input before this, must be ended with a newline.